# input in ionic 2 iframe does not work on ios or ipad

Tags: ios, ionic2, wkwebview

I have an iFrame in my ionic 2 app which loads a website managed by my clients. when I build the app in ios and try to run it on ipad, the input box wont receive any text input. I can see that it is getting focused but user is not able to type in anything. This happens only with ios. I am running the app on ios 9+. So far I have tried the following,

1. removing -webkit-user-select: none and replacing with -webkit-user-select: text !important; in input on my ionic css.
2. using wkWebView plugin from https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine. I can type in the input boxes in the iframe with this but non of my server calls are working even when I have added the allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin to *

any help is appreciated.

Comment: CORS issue maybe

Comment: My server is already handling it.